# Prism scultpure Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism, sculpture

Using Prism Scultpure I am facing this problem

Can some one help me what to do. I have R1 Region but it raise the follwoing error

The bold line in the following code is the error

```
public virtual void StartAction()
        {
            global::System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new global::System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new global::System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.StartActionWorker);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            CandidateView candidateView = null;
            foreach (object view in **this.RegionManager.Regions["R1"].Views**)
            {
                if (true == view is CandidateView)
                {
                    candidateView = view as CandidateView;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (null == candidateView)
            {
                candidateView = this.Container.GetExportedValue<CandidateView>();
                this.RegionManager.Regions["R1"].Add(candidateView);
            }

            this.RegionManager.Regions["R1"].Activate(candidateView);
        }
```

The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information. 1) The region manager does not contain the R1 region. Resulting in: An exception occurred while initializing module 'CandidateMModule'. - The exception message was: The region manager does not contain the R1 region. - The Assembly that the module was trying to be loaded from was:Candidate, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Check the InnerException property of the exception for more information. If the exception occurred while creating an object in a DI container, you can exception.GetRootException() to help locate the root cause of the problem. Resulting in: An exception occurred while calling the 'OnImportsSatisfied' method on type 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'. Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'. Element: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager --> Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager --> AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35") Resulting in: Cannot get export 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager (ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleManager")' from part 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager'. Element: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager (ContractName="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModuleManager") --> Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity.MefModuleManager --> AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to populate the region before it's loaded. Check if the region is registered with `RegionManager.Regions.ContainsRegionWithName("R1")`